# Convert single column of a DataTable to CSV

Tags: vb.net, csv, datatable

Using VB.NET, what is the most concise way to convert a single column of a DataTable to a CSV?  The values are integers, so I don't need to worry about character escaping or encoding.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What do you mean with "convert to CSV"? If you want to generate a string with comma-separated values, you can use this(`tbl` is your DataTable and `Int-Column` is the name of the DataColumn):

```
String.Join(",", (From row In tbl.AsEnumerable Select row("Int-Column")).ToArray)
```

A CSV normally is a file-format where the columns are separated by comma(or other separators) and the rows are separated by new lines. Hence you simply have to replace `String.Join(","` with `String.Join(Environment.NewLine`

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

Sorry, I really meant to say "a string of values, separated by a comma delimiter" instead of "CSV". But you hit the nail on the head with your answer anyway -- thank you!