# How to add commas between array members, etc?

Tags: c#

I simply add comma next to each word:

```
 foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
 {                {
    sqlIn += row["personId"] + ", ";
 }
```

Then I remove the last comma which one is unnecessary:

```
 sqlIn = sqlIn.TrimEnd(' ', ',');
```

And I feel like in the days of classic ASP. Is there any C# version of what I do?

Comment: Why not use a List or Collection and add every result to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further to Bas B answer Correct syntax is

```
 string s = String.Join(", ", ds.Tables[0].Select().Select(r => r["personID"].ToString()));
```

Here is working proof

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data;


    namespace ConsoleApplication5
    {
      class Program
      {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          DataSet ds = new DataSet();

          DataTable dt = new DataTable();
          ds.Tables.Add(dt);
          string col = "personId";
          dt.Columns.Add(col, typeof(int));

          dt.Rows.Add(1);
          dt.Rows.Add(2);

          string s = String.Join(", ", ds.Tables[0].Select().Select(r => r["personID"].ToString()));

          Console.WriteLine(s);
          Console.ReadLine();

        }
      }

    }
```

---

Output will be

```
1, 2
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `String.Join`

```
String.Join(", ", ds.Tables[0].Rows.Select(r => r["personId"].ToString()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `String.Join` method - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx for possible overloads.

Answer (score 1):

you want it to convert in CSV.

you can use following `String.Join` overloads:

(**Method 1**) **[String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx)** after converting the column values to a array or

(**Method 2**) you can use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) overload  `Join(Of T)(String, IEnumerable(Of T))`, Select Extension method will return the IEnumerable of String type value.

**Method 1:**

```
String.Join(",", (From row In ds.Tables[0].Rows.AsEnumerable Select row["personId")).ToArray)
```

**Method 2:**

```
String.Join(", ", ds.Tables[0].Rows.Select(row => row["personId"].ToString()));
```

follow this SO Thread for reference: [Convert single column of a DataTable to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149014/convert-single-column-of-a-datatable-to-csv)